# Cancel /DEBUG on Visual Studio's link command

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

Is there a way to cancel the `/DEBUG` command line argument on Visual Studio's (2015+) link command?

I've tried  `/DEBUG:NO` and `/DEBUG-` but neither is recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project's properties, select the `Linker -> Debugging` options page and turn off "Generate Debug Info," as shown below:

[image]

(If this option is *not* shown, be sure that all other 'debug' options are disabled, such as "Use Debug Libraries" on the `Configuration Properties -> Advanced` page.)

Alternatively, to *explicitly* turn off the `/DEBUG` option in command-line builds, you can use the `/DEBUG:NONE` switch.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm looking for a command line option that would undo `/DEBUG`. The reason I'm asking this is that I'm generating the VS projects using CMake, and the (complex) build setup I'm dealing with adds `/DEBUG` to the linker's command line. I'm wondering if there's a way to follow this up with something that would turn debug info back off.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune See the appended edit to my answer - hope it helps!